# wifi adapter lost - 22.04 - Broadcom - Realtek

Tags: drivers, wireless, kernel, broadcom, realtek-wireless

I suddenly lost the wifi capability of my ThinkPad E145. The easy fixes suggested on forums did not work. System is up to date (update, upgrade, autoremove done) and there is wired internet on this computer and wifi on other devices.

Output of sudo lshw -class network is:

*-network UNCLAIMED
description: Network controller
product: BCM43142 802.11b/g/n
vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
physical id: 0
bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
version: 01
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
configuration: latency=0
resources: memory:f1300000-f1307fff
*-network
description: Ethernet interface
product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
physical id: 0
bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
logical name: eth0
version: 07
serial: c4:54:44:6c:bb:48
size: 100Mbit/s
capacity: 1Gbit/s
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.15.0-67-generic duplex=full firmware=rtl8168e-3_0.0.4 03/27/12 ip=192.168.1.8 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
resources: irq:30 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:f0904000-f0904fff memory:f0900000-f0903fff

The "Additional drivers" section of Software&Updates shows:
Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries: BCM43142802.11b/g/n

- Broadcom 802.11 Linux STA wireless driver source from: bcmwl-kernel-source (closed)
- Device not used (This is selected)

When I want to switch (back) to the Broadcom driver, I get the following message:
"pk-client-error-quark: Error while installing package: installed bcmwl-kernel-source package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10(313)"

Your answers and comments are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Let's see if we can gather some informative clues. In a terminal: `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt purge bcmwl-kernel-source` and finally: `sudo apt install bcmwl-kernel-source` Please post the errors, warnings, et al. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: sudo apt install bcmwl-kernel-source:
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/bcmwl-kernel-so
urce.0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.15.0-67-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/make.log for more informati
on.
dpkg: hiba a csomag feldolgozásakor: bcmwl-kernel-source (--configure):
 installed bcmwl-kernel-source package post-installation script subprocess retur
ned error exit status 10
Hibák történtek a feldolgozáskor:
 bcmwl-kernel-source
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: "hiba a csomag feldolgozásakor" = error while processing package
"Hibák történtek a feldolgozáskor" = there were errors while processing

Comment: "Consult /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/make.log for more information" Please run: `cat /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/make.log` Paste the result here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/ZjFfqMZ76X/

Comment: make: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-67-generic'

  ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid.
         include/generated/autoconf.h or include/config/auto.conf are missing.
         Run 'make oldconfig && make prepare' on kernel src to fix it.

make: *** [Makefile:750: include/config/auto.conf] Error 1
make: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-67-generic'

Comment: Please try: `sudo apt install --reinstall linux-headers-generic linux-headers-5.15.0-67-generic` and try again.

Comment: PROBLEM SOLVED! THANK YOU SO MUCH FOR YOUR HELP!